# How to specify in the intent-filter not to receive intents whose extra is null

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an Android application. For some reason, I want my application not to show in the chooser dialog when the intent's extra is null. Actually, the null extra will crash my application. Is there any way that I can specify such information in intent-filter?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should solve the crash though...

Comment: @dtmilano Thanks! Yes. I can solve the crash. But I think if preventing user choose my application at first place may be a better choice. But the current intent passing system seems have limited expressiveness to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think no. What about checking for null?

```
if( getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want my app not showing in app choosers when the intent containing null extra was sent. So we can only use exception handling to alleviate this issue?